# Chrome Built in Flash Player Sends incorrect Referer

Tags: security, google-chrome, http-headers, flash

I have noised that chrome built-in flash player acts different compared with previous versions and current version of Adobe Flash Player.
The Problem is that when we embed some swf (http://example.com/hosted.swf) on our webpage (http://example.com/page1.html)  and our swf load some external resources (http://example.com/video.flv) the request "REFERER" header is "http://example.com/page1.html" in previous versions and in Adobe's version it is "http://example.com/hosted.swf".
This causes issues when we protect content with REFERER header to be sure that requested content is loaded with our hosted swf.
Does anyone know a solution to force chrome built-in player act same way like Adobe Player(JS or HTML Tip)?

Comment: IMHO, guarding a URL based on the `HTTP_REFERER` header isn't really guarding it at all, since a client (or proxy, in the case of really dumb clients) can change this header arbitrarily.